# Using maven-release-plugin with GitHub "You can't push to git://github.com/..."

Tags: maven, github, maven-release-plugin, sonatype, maven-scm

Recently having switched source code repository for a project to GitHub from SourceForge I need to update the maven release process to match. I followed [this link](http://www.owengriffin.com/posts/2010/04/15/Releasing_Maven_projects_to_Github.html) for configuring the "scm" section of the pom. The GitHub repository is [shown here](https://github.com/datanucleus/datanucleus-maven-parent). Everything else is as it was when using SVN (for publishing to https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide#SonatypeOSSMavenRepositoryUsageGuide-4.MavenRepositories). So then I invoke

```
mvn clean release:clean release:prepare release:perform
```

and the output is as follows

```
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.1:prepare (default-cli) @ datanucleus-maven-parent ---
[INFO] Verifying that there are no local modifications...
[INFO]   ignoring changes on: pom.xml.next, release.properties, pom.xml.releaseBackup, pom.xml.backup, pom.xml.branch, pom.xml.tag
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/andy/work/datanucleus/datanucleus-maven-parent && git status
[INFO] Working directory: /home/andy/work/datanucleus/datanucleus-maven-parent
[INFO] Checking dependencies and plugins for snapshots ...
What is the release version for "DataNucleus Maven parent project"? (org.datanucleus:datanucleus-maven-parent) 3.3: : 
What is SCM release tag or label for "DataNucleus Maven parent project"? (org.datanucleus:datanucleus-maven-parent) datanucleus-maven-parent-3.3: : 
What is the new development version for "DataNucleus Maven parent project"? (org.datanucleus:datanucleus-maven-parent) 3.4-SNAPSHOT: : 
[INFO] Transforming 'DataNucleus Maven parent project'...
[INFO] Not generating release POMs
[INFO] Executing goals 'clean verify'...
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/andy/work/datanucleus/datanucleus-maven-parent && /usr/local/maven3/bin/mvn clean verify --no-plugin-updates -Psonatype-oss-release -P development
    [WARNING] Command line option -npu is deprecated and will be removed in future Maven versions.
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building DataNucleus Maven parent project 3.3
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ datanucleus-maven-parent ---
    [INFO] Deleting /home/andy/work/datanucleus/datanucleus-maven-parent (includes = [*.log], excludes = [])
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (enforce-maven) @ datanucleus-maven-parent ---
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-bundle-plugin:2.4.0:manifest (default) @ datanucleus-maven-parent ---
    [WARNING] Ignoring project type pom - supportedProjectTypes = [jar, bundle]
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.1.2:jar-no-fork (attach-sources) @ datanucleus-maven-parent ---
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-javadoc-plugin:2.7:jar (attach-javadocs) @ datanucleus-maven-parent ---
    [INFO] Not executing Javadoc as the project is not a Java classpath-capable package
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-gpg-plugin:1.1:sign (sign-artifacts) @ datanucleus-maven-parent ---
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 1.535s
    [INFO] Finished at: Sat Dec 14 08:51:07 GMT 2013
    [INFO] Final Memory: 14M/491M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Checking in modified POMs...
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/andy/work/datanucleus/datanucleus-maven-parent && git add -- pom.xml
[INFO] Working directory: /home/andy/work/datanucleus/datanucleus-maven-parent
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/andy/work/datanucleus/datanucleus-maven-parent && git status
[INFO] Working directory: /home/andy/work/datanucleus/datanucleus-maven-parent
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/andy/work/datanucleus/datanucleus-maven-parent && git commit --verbose -F /tmp/maven-scm-1907822841.commit pom.xml
[INFO] Working directory: /home/andy/work/datanucleus/datanucleus-maven-parent
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/andy/work/datanucleus/datanucleus-maven-parent && git symbolic-ref HEAD
[INFO] Working directory: /home/andy/work/datanucleus/datanucleus-maven-parent
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/andy/work/datanucleus/datanucleus-maven-parent && git push git://github.com/datanucleus/datanucleus-maven-parent.git master:master
[INFO] Working directory: /home/andy/work/datanucleus/datanucleus-maven-parent
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.885s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Dec 14 08:51:07 GMT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/491M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.1:prepare (default-cli) on project datanucleus-maven-parent: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] fatal: remote error:
[ERROR] You can't push to git://github.com/datanucleus/datanucleus-maven-parent.git
[ERROR] Use https://github.com/datanucleus/datanucleus-maven-parent.git
```

Now a connection of "scm:git:git://github.com/{organization}/{project}.git" is what all examples I've seen for maven-release-plugin so would appreciate any insight in why it doesn't work here, or what I could look at to find out why. I can do a git push to the same URL using the user I'm logged on here as (GitHub has the SSH key).

I tried swapping the scm connection/developerConnection over to https and then get username/password prompted and it then hangs (it updates the GitHub repo with the version without SNAPSHOT) but that's all.

Comment: Apart from that i would suggest to use up-to-date maven-release-plugin (2.4.2) instead of an old one (2.1).

Comment: yes agreed, but that's specified in the Sonatype parent POM for all projects publishing to Sonatype (even though I can override it)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually the problem was more of believing web links of how you should configure your SCM section, so I post the answer here in case anyone else hits this message. The connection/developerConnection should be of the form

```
scm:git:git@github.com:{organization}/{project}.git
```

Comment: It didn't worked for me. I am getting push failed with a dialog saying "No supported authentication method found (server sent public key). Can you help me with this error ?

Comment: It did work for me (I had the https:// version). @coding_idiot, did you add your public ssh key to your github account?