# AT-Sign in hostname on release:perform

Tags: java, maven, github, maven-release-plugin

I try to release a Project in GitHub using Maven.

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/jenkinsci/jabber-server-plugin.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com/jenkinsci/jabber-server-plugin.git</developerConnection>
    <url>http://github.com/jenkinsci/jabber-server-plugin</url>
</scm>
```

Unfortunately maven fails to git-clone to a server `@github.com`.

Full story:

```
fatal: Unable to look up @github.com (port 9418) 
  (Beim Datenbankaufruf ist ein nicht behebbarer Fehler aufgetreten. )
```

Any suggestions what i need to do to force the hostname `github.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using windows this is not possible. I installed debian using virtualbox and this is the story:

1. java -version (gives me openjdk, from experiences i know: i need a oracle/sun's jdk)
2. (download java from oracle and install, `export JAVA_HOME...`-stuff also)
3. java -version (gives me oracle/sun jdk now, fine)
4. su
5. apt-get install maven
6. apt-get install git
7. apt-get install jenkins
8. exit
9. git clone https://github.com/jenkinsci/jabber-server-plugin
10. cd jabber-server-plugin
11. su
12. vi /etc/maven/settings.xml (add mirror ...)
13. exit
14. mvn release:prepare release:perform (error pid-file cant be written)
15. su
16. /etc/init.d/jenkins stop
17. exit
18. mvn release:prepare release:perform (error: github-user-unknown)
19. ssh-add github-private-key (enter password)
20. mvn release:prepare release:perform (error: jenkins-ci.org 401)
21. mvn release:prepare release:perform -Dpassword -Dusername (error: github takes jenkins-ci.org's password instead keystore, darn)
22. su
23. vi /etc/maven/settings.xml (move password and username from -Dparam to maven's  part)
24. exit
25. mvn release:prepare release:perform (error: 401, i read doc and i need to paste the encryptet-password (slat or something more))
26. https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/webapp (Login, open my account, unlock to edit profile, copy encryptet password).
27. vi /etc/maven/settings.xml (overwrite the 's password from clipboard )
28. mvn release:prepare release:perform

**BUILD SUCCESS**

*(mental stagedive)*

Comment: Good feedback, more complete than my answer. +1

Comment: @VonC You are welcome. I would not be able to solve this problem without your pressure to use a certificate!

Comment: After restart a simple `ssh-add github-private-key` and `mvn release:prepare release:perform` is enougth.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you need to specify the ssh user `git@`:

```
<developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:jenkinsci/jabber-server-plugin.git</developerConnection>
```

That is: '`:`' instead of '`/`' after `github.com`, as illustrated in:

- "[Maven Tips](http://blog.sonatype.com/2009/09/maven-tips-and-tricks-using-github/#.U5iyI_l_vfI)",
- "[Using `maven-release-plugin` with GitHub “`You can't push to git://github.com/…`”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20581541/6309)"
- "[`example/pom.xml`](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/github-maven-example/blob/master/example/pom.xml)"

---

If that still fails, you have some workaround possible:

If you want to keep an ssh url for the developerConnection part, try to see if the [url examples](http://maven.apache.org/scm/git.html) work better:

```
scm:git:ssh://server_name[:port]/path_to_repository
```

That is:

```
<developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/jenkinsci/jabber-server-plugin.git</developerConnection>
```

(so specifying explicitly the `ssh://` protocol, as used in "[How to Use Maven Release Plugin with GitHub Releases](http://blog.glassdiary.com/post/64370899685/how-to-use-maven-release-plugin-with-github-releases)")

---

As a last resort, you could try another protocol which doesn't have to use a non-default port or ssh, like the https one, as listed in [Maven SCM Git](http://maven.apache.org/scm/git.html):

```
scm:git:https://server_name[:port]/path_to_repository
```

That would give:

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:https://github.com/jenkinsci/jabber-server-plugin.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:https://yourLogin@github.com/jenkinsci/jabber-server-plugin.git</developerConnection>
    <url>http://github.com/jenkinsci/jabber-server-plugin</url>
</scm>
```

Comment: BTW: for `:` instead of `/` i had to `ssh-add .ssh/id_rsa`. After that `release:perform` ran into a NPE.

Comment: @PeterRader try first with an ssh key without passphrase (no need to `ssh-add` then) for testing purpose.

Comment: I tried this an ran into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243755/maven-error-releasing-code-to-github-hangs-after-push . Anyway the NPE is actually the problem caused at `InstallMojo.execute(InstallMojo.java:116)`. Ill investigate the code now...

Comment: @PeterRader I didn't remember having answered that one too!

Comment: even if i have a ssh key without passphrase (not sure how that can be possible - i always are asked for a passphrase), i need to add the key anyway to a agent. Is there a benefit i do not see without a passprase? The NPE causes on the `maven-release-plugin` in version `2.0-beta-9` i will try to upgrade the plugin.

Comment: @PeterRader simply hit return when ask for a passphrase ;)

Comment: @PeterRader since yu have a passphrase-protected key, this isn't related to http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-deployment-security-settings.html, is it?

Comment: yes it is, but i dont see why this method should be used if its more easy to add the key via commandline. i guess we are far away from the NPE bug and from my question.

Comment: @PeterRader I agree, I was just checking. Anyway, I would still try with a simpler ssh key, just to rule that out.

Answer (score 0):

Following should work for your project

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/jenkinsci/jabber-server-plugin.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:jenkinsci/jabber-server-plugin.git</developerConnection>
    <url>http://github.com/jenkinsci/jabber-server-plugin</url>
</scm>
```

Comment: This is exactly the same what VonC said.

Comment: More ore less. He proposed to use for <connection> a different protocoll, which is (from my point of view) is not necessary. I bundled everything together. So it woul de easier for others to get a backed solution. But I agree: there was nothing not yet mentioned on this page in my answer. ;-)